# Загрузка файлов средствами wordpress (wp_handle_upload)

Tags: php, wordpress, fileupload, upload

Доброго времени суток.

Работаю с wordpress, а именно над написанием плагина. Моя задача заключается в загрузке картинок с компьютера на сервер, далее нужно выдать мне url и сохранить его в отдельную таблицу в БД.

В основе всего использую функцию wp_handle_upload примерно таким образом:

```
  if (count($_FILES) > 5) {
            echo 'Слишком много файлов!';
            return 0;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES) - 1; $i++) {
            $file = $_FILES[$i];

            //print_r($file);
            $overrides = array('test_form' => false);

            $move_file = wp_handle_upload($file, $overrides);

            if ($move_file) {
                echo 'It`s work';
                echo $move_file;

            } else {
                echo 'Ничего не работает.';
                print_r($move_file);
            }
        }
```

Далее получаю вроде такого сообщения:

```
Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => 69618.jpg [1] => banff-canada-lake-national.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpTWjUPN [1] => /tmp/phpuh8fFD ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 232720 [1] => 286619 ) ) )
```

, что должно было бы сообщить об успешной загрузке. 
Но, меня смущает путь загрузки, а именно "/tmp/phpTWjUPN". Я хочу, что бы все картинки загружались в wp-content/uploads, ну и оттуда я их в будущем и дергал.

Так вот, что для этого использовать и как подобное реализовать?

Comment: А какие параметры в $overrides?

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно напрасно смущает `/tmp/phpTWjUPN` — после отправки формы файлы помещаются во временную директорию `tmp`.

Задача php-обработчика — переместить их оттуда в место постоянного хранения. В php даже есть специальная функция для этого https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php.

Функции wordpress для загрузки используют массив `$_FILES` и эту функцию, чтобы поместить файлы в `wp-content/uploads`.

P.S. А вот обработка ошибок при загрузке неправильная, `$res = wp_handle_upload()` возвращает массив, и попытка проверить массив с помощью `if($res)` всегда будет выдавать `true`

```
$res = wp_handle_upload(...);
if (isset($res['error'])) {
    echo 'Ошибка при загрузке файла';
} else {
    echo 'Файл был успешно загружен';
}
```